# Is there any callbacks which help to detect when application gets killed (swipe, app crashed)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

Unlike **Activity**, which has a clear lifecycle (onCreate ... onDestroy), **Application** only has onCreate method. I want to handle some events when the app gets destroyed, but yet find any solution for this. I have read some topic related to this issue, they suggested me to use **Service**. Does anybody have another solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: When a user or the system force stops your application, the entire process is simply killed. There is no callback made to inform you that this has happened.

    When the user uninstalls the app, at first the process is killed, then your apk file and data directory are deleted, along with the records in Package Manager that tell other apps which intent filters you've registered for.

Comment: Use Service. It is the only simple solution

Comment: The `Application` instance never gets destroyed. Android just kills off the OS process hosting the application when it wants to reclaim resources. There are no callbacks. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BhuvaneshBS Why do you think using a `Service` will help solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) from architecture component library.

```
MyClass : LifecycleObserver
{
    init
    {
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get( ).getLifecycle( ).addObserver( this );
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent( Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onAppCreate( )
    {

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent( Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onAppStart( )
    {

    }

    ...

    @OnLifecycleEvent( Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onAppDestroy( )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help. If Android kills the hosting OS process (which is what it does when it wants to reclaim resources), none of these lifecycle callbacks are made.